# routerLinkActive not working in unit testing

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

RouterLinkActive is not working during unit testing but It works when outside unit testing.

Here is HTML:

```
<header class="site-tab">
  <nav class="c-tab l-wrap">
    <div
      class="c-tab__item"
      routerLink="/companies"
      routerLinkActive="c-tab__item--active"
    >
      <p class="c-tab__text">Companies</p>
    </div>
    <div
      class="c-tab__item"
      routerLink="/products"
      routerLinkActive="c-tab__item--active"
    >
      <p class="c-tab__text">Products</p>
    </div>
    <div
      class="c-tab__item"
      routerLink="/invoices"
      routerLinkActive="c-tab__item--active"
    >
      <p class="c-tab__text">Invoices</p>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

and here is my spec file:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { TabsComponent } from './tabs.component';

describe('TabsComponent', () => {
  let component: TabsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TabsComponent>;
  let de: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TabsComponent],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TabsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    de = fixture.debugElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should set clicked tab to active', () => {
    de.queryAll(By.css('.c-tab__item'))[1].nativeElement.click();
    expect(
      de.query(By.css('.c-tab__item--active .c-tab__text')).nativeElement
        .innerHTML
    ).toContain('Product');
  });
```

I expect the tab to be active once I click on it but I am getting this error
`TypeError: de.query(...) is null in http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js (line 872)` which I believe means that no tab was set to active.

Comment: why do you use debug element and then call native element? fixture.nativeElement should work.

Comment: I assume your saying that my click function did not work? Can you more elaborate on how to click the tab from unit testing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not sure if `clicking` will do the `router` magic but it might. But I believe you're missing a `fixture.detectChanges()` after the click.

Try:

```
  it('should set clicked tab to active', () => {
    de.queryAll(By.css('.c-tab__item'))[1].nativeElement.click();
    fixture.detectChanges(); // add this.
    expect(
      de.query(By.css('.c-tab__item--active .c-tab__text')).nativeElement
        .innerHTML
    ).toContain('Product');
  });
```

Comment: i was able to do this using router.navigate, but that seems to be working fine as well. thanks.

Comment: still not able to get the active class in selector in spec.ts

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue, even while reading this issue also.
But i got the solution after applying the `fakeAsync` function and `tick()`.

```
     it('should set clicked tab to active', fakeAsync(() => {
        de.queryAll(By.css('.c-tab__item'))[1].nativeElement.click();
        fixture.detectChanges(); // add this
        tick(); // add this too
        expect(
          de.query(By.css('.c-tab__item--active .c-tab__text')).nativeElement
            .innerHTML
        ).toContain('Product');
      }));
```